# use cron and script to keep a file with computer's ip in a dropbox folder

Tags: shell, cron

I want to use Dropbox to keep track of my computer's IP address.

I was thinking of using `crond` to run a shell script every 5 minutes that asks icanhazip.com what my ip address is and then edit a file to have the current ip of that computer.

So i think the script would go something like this

```
CurrentIP = curl -s http://icanhazip.com/
echo $CurrentIP > ~/Dropbox/ComputerIP
```

then I would add an entry to crontab that would tell it to run every ten minutes

```
*/5 * * * * UpdateIP.sh
```

Mind you, this is my first shell script, so I have no idea what I´m doing, and would appreciate any input into how to do this more elegantly

Comment: Be aware that `*/5 * * * * UpdateIP.sh` won't work, you have to add sh route, like `*/5 * * * * /bin/sh UpdateIP.sh`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to run your command directly from cron:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -s http://icanhazip.com/ > ~/Dropbox/ComputerIP
```

(include the correct full-path to your curl command).

Of course, if you expect that you'd need to perform a more complicated task in the future, it is better to leave it in a script, as you already do.